# Why counter is coming twice in console with different values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was experimenting with React 'ref' and was playing with below code snippet.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Button = () => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const btnRef = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {
        btnRef.current.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('counter ', counter);
            setCounter(counter => 1);
        })
    })

    return (
        <button ref={btnRef}>Click Me</button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

What I couldn't understand is this code snippet is giving me 'counter' value twice in the console and with different values, every time I clicked on the button. Could someone help me in understanding what's happening here.

Why counter value is showing '0' again and again, when already its changed via setCounter function ?

Comment: You're missing the empty dependency array in `useEffect`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have placed the dependency []. But state is not getting updated now on each click of button. Could you tell me why ? Thanks again.

Comment: What is `setCounter(counter => 1);` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

when you don't pass a dependency array, `useEffect` is triggered on every render including the first. So it renders for the first time, then you call `setCounter`, which triggers render the second time. You probably looking for this;

```
 useEffect(() => {
        btnRef.current.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('counter ', counter);
            setCounter(counter => 1);
        })
    },[]) // <-- this is an empty dependency array
```

Comment: Thanks. I passed the empty [] as dependency, now console is showing only one value. But it's not updating the state, counter state is not getting set to '1'. On every click, counter value shows as '0'.